# Typescript type for limiting assignment

Tags: typescript, union-types

Given:

```
interface B {
    base: string;
}
interface C1 extends B {
    c1: string;
}
interface C2 extends B {
    c2: string;
}

type A = C1 | C2;

var aOk1: A = {
    base: '',
    c1: '',
}
var aOk2: A = {
    base: '',
    c2: '',
}
var a: A = {
    base: '',
    c1: '', // was expecting this to error at compile time
    c2: '', // was expecting this to error at compile time
}

a.c1; // Correctly errors
a.c2; // Correctly errors
```

As marked in the code, I was expecting the assignment of both `c1` and `c2` attributes to result in a compile time error.  Is there any way of achieving this?

To clarify **the motive**, it is because there are two mutually exclusive ways of setting an options object and I was hoping to type it in a definition (`.d.ts`) file using:

```
// definition in a .d.ts file
someFunction(options: C1 | C2)
```

So that if someone tried to incorrectly pass an options object with both values set they would be shown an error at compile time but instead they can currently do the following without any compile time error:

```
// consuming in a .ts file

// User might think both options will be used but
// actually c2 option silently overrides c1.
someFunction({base: '', c1: '', c2: ''});
```

** **Edit: Tagged union types** **

You can't solve this using [tagged union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tagged-union-types) also known as ["Discriminated Unions"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) either:

```
interface C1 extends B {
    kind: 'C1',
    c1: string;
}
interface C2 extends B {
    kind: 'C2',
    c2: string;
}

type A = C1 | C2;

var a: A = {
    kind: 'C1',
    base: '',
    c1: '', // would like this to compile time error
    c2: '', // would like this to compile time error
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for intersection types? `type A = C1 & C2;`

Comment: Hey @Saravana, thanks for the comment.  Intersection type firstly does not result in `c1` and `c2` in `var a: A = {base:'',c1:'',c2:''}` erroring correctly (and additionally results in being able to access c1 and c2 without any error which is definitely not correct).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a solution to this yet but there is related discussion here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12997
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12745